# How to resolve views residing in different folder in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.0.5 and InternalResourceViewResolver to resolving the views. Now if I put all the .jsp files into WEB-INF/pages/view and use configuration like:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/view</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

the pages resolving correctly.

But for different module I want to put my .jsp files in separate folders. For example package WEB-INF/pages/view/booking and WEB-INF/pages/view/quote will contain .jsp files for Booking and Quote module  correspondingly.

How can I do such configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure such configuration is easily possible. But there is another easy approach to having your views in different directories. Just use the common part of the path as prefix (`/WEB-INF/pages/view/`) in your view resolver configuration and then return the relative path of your view to the specified prefix from your controller:

- `booking/home` -> will be resolved to `/WEB-INF/pages/view/booking/home.jsp`
- `quote/home` -> will be resolved to `/WEB-INF/pages/view/quote/home.jsp`